# Laravel S3 connector (selfhosted S3 with docker)

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3

I'm hosting my own `S3Server` on `DigitalOcean` using the Docker image [scality/s3server](https://hub.docker.com/r/scality/s3server/)

Previously i have been using Amazon S3 server, so i used the league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 library for the connection.

Now, because i'm using my own server, i need to change the S3 endpoint that the connector use.

I have tried this configuration in the filesystems.php:

```
'disks' => [
    's3' => [
        'driver'    => 's3',
        'key'       => 'accessKey1',
        'secret'    => 'verySecretKey1',
        'bucket'    => 'mybucket',
        'base_url'  => 'http://my_digitalocean_ip:8000'
    ]
]
```

The connector still attempts to access https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer myself.
The configuration option should be "endpoint" in stead of "base_url".

```
'disks' => [
    's3' => [
        'driver'    => 's3',
        'key'       => 'accessKey1',
        'secret'    => 'verySecretKey1',
        'bucket'    => 'mybucket',
        'endpoint'  => 'http://my_digitalocean_ip:8000'
    ]
]
```

Now it works.

I also chose to go with another storage system called [minio](https://hub.docker.com/r/minio/minio/). It's more intuitive i think, and it has a browserbased GUI.